# Anything that can text geocoords?

Tags: geolocation

I'd like to text someone my location so they can use something like maps.google.com and navigate to me. Any app or technique that makes this task easier than putzing around asking for the address?

Comment: Is Google Maps' "check-in" feature not working for you?

Comment: looking for something more like offby1's suggestion below. I want to tell just one person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps can do this.  Long-press the map at your location; a popup should appear with the address; you can tap that and it'll give you the option to "share" that location.  From that you can send a text, email, etc.

Comment: Man, that's really cool and exactly what I want but highly inaccurate. This is the msg generated, "My Location@7:25pm,6/3 2200-2298 Green Oak Dr, Kingwood, TX 77339 http://m.google.com/u/m/Bqorao". Unfortunately, I'm on the whole other side of Kingwood Drive though at the Starbucks, probably 500 feet away. Anything more accurate?

Comment: I doubt it; the accuracy (or lack of it!) is probably due to the phone's internal GPS stuff, and I expect every app -- including Google Maps -- merely uses that data, without having any way to improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

[Glympse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glympse.android.glympse) is really good for this.

Basically, you set up a time-limited "glympse" of your location. You can then share that "glympse" via a number of channels, including SMS. The recipient need not be a Glympse user and can follow your progress on the Glympse website. Access is automatically revoked at the end of the time limit, thwarting your would-be stalkers.

The usual caveats of it's only as accurate as the GPS location reported by your device.

Answer (score 0):

The "Hangouts" app on my (stock Android 4.4.2) phone does this, but in a fairly non-intuitive way:

1. Open Hangouts
2. Either tap the + in the upper-right, or tap an existing hangout
3. At the bottom, there's a text area that says "Send Hangouts message".  Just to the right is a paper-clip icon; tap that.
4. That will reveal a menu with three choices; the last choice is "Location".  Tap that.
5. You will see a map labeled "Share Location".  (I assume you can scroll the map around to adjust the location, but I haven't tried that.)  To the right of the label is a little paper-airplane icon.  Tap that.
6. You should see a (rather large) thumbnail of the map, superimposed over the Hangouts text area; the text area will have in it (in faint type) "Location Ready To Send".  Tap the paper-airplane icon.

Answer (score -1):

I just googled for "share my location android", and the first hit looks pertinent: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sylvek.sharemyposition